# Como se puede pasar información de Modal a home.page.ts?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4, firebase-auth

Bien, la cosa es, que pasar información por ejemplo desde `home.page.ts` a la página de Modal, es sencillo, pero la pregunta es que como se puede hacer a la inversa, es decir, del Modal a `home.page.ts`.

He hecho un login con todas las funciones ya para iniciar sesión con `firebase`, pero cuando abro el modal e introduzco los datos de la cuenta, no me detecta la cuenta el `home.page.ts` después de cerrar el Modal.

Tal vez tengo que pasar algún parámetro y recibirlo con `NavParams`o algo y no me estoy dando cuenta. Pero claro, si en el `app-routing.module.ts` pongo por ejemplo `home/:id` me da error si no tengo un `id` no?

Ayuda pls.

Código del `login.page.ts` (Modal)

```
async login(){

const { username, passwd } = this

    try {

        const res = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username + '@myapp.com', passwd)

        if(res.user) {
            this.userSvc.setUser({
                username,
                uid: res.user.uid
            })

    this.closeModal()

        }

    } catch(err) {
  console.dir(err)

    }

  }
```

Comment: Puedes poner el código?

Comment: Si, acabo de publicarlo!

Comment: Creo que si tienes que pasar toda la información desde el NavParams.

Comment: Intenta mostrar en consola el NavParams desde el home.ts para ver que data te trae.

Comment: Guíate de la documentación esta muy bien explicado para pasar data desde un modal. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRxPOs1OM34

Comment: Guíate de ese vídeo, saludos.

Comment: Gracias!! Un saludo.